# TRIS Instruction PIC16F178x family

Tags: pic

Good day to all.

I'm working with the PIC16F1782 family of enhanced 14-bit PICs.  These include: 1782, 1783, 1784, 1786, 1787.

The instruction set in the datasheet shows that the TRIS instruction is supported, unlike some older members of the 14-bit family.  However, it's not working for me.

The 16F178x family has moved some of the registers around compared to earlier PICs.  Specifically, there are two INDF and FSR registers instead of only one.  As a result, ports RA through RC have been moved from 0x05..0x07 to 0x0C..0x0E.

When I run MPASMWIN version 8.92, I get errors anytime a TRIS instruction is encountered.  The error message says that the allowable address range of TRIS is 0x05..0x07.

Is this a problem with MPASMWIN or is the datasheet not correct?

I can always go back to switching RAM banks to load the TRIS registers but it would sure be convenient (and faster/shorter) if I could go back to using the TRIS instruction.

Guidance gratefully accepted.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried MPLAB X IDE, and select the specific PIC that you are using from the dropdown. That would make your program particular PIC specific and should sort out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Microchip don't recommend it, you *can* use the TRIS instruction. The trick is to read the datasheet carefully:-

[image]

Comment: This works with early PIC controllers.  The addresses for ports RA through RC is 0x05..0x07.  However, the 16F178x family has ports RA..RC located at addresses 0x0C..0x0E.  Note how the instruction says that the operand is the address of the port register.

Comment: @Dwayne Reid I don't have a 16F1782-7 so I can't verify 100%, but I have tested a 16F1824 (which has similar SFR mapping) and `TRIS 5` **did** load TRISA - despite being at address 0x8C, not 5. So the datasheet and simulator are both correct (at least for my PIC, and probably for the others also).